# Is there any way to find in which file - file is included

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, zend-framework

Am sure the question is vague.

Let me try to explain.

Assume zend frame work  - PHP - jquery combination.

I include jquery files  in layout.phtml.

i include some files in controller.php.

some file in view.phtml

Atlast when i run and view the page . Is there any way or any tool to find which file is included through which file (layout controller or view) ??

In addition can some one explain which is the best way include js files and where . using zend framework in layout or controller or view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to find where a public, static asset (JS, CSS, image, etc) is included is to trawl through the source code (using something that can "find in files" would save time).

In regards to how and where to include such assets... for global includes (common stylesheets, scripts, etc), include these in your layouts.

For specific page includes, place these in your views.

The best way to include a static asset is using the appropriate view helper. These are generally displayed in your layout file, for example

```
<?php echo $this->doctype() ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php

        echo $this->headMeta()->prependHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=' . $this->getEncoding());

        // I use "prepend" here so it comes before any page specific stylesheets
        echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl('/css/common.css'));

        echo $this->headScript();

        ?>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- content -->

        <?php echo $this->inlineScript() ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can then add to these placeholders in your view scripts, for example

```
<?php
// index/index.phtml
$this->inlineScript()->appendFile('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js')
                     ->appendFile($this->baseUrl('/js/my-jquery-script.js'));
```

Answer (score 1):

To "include" a file means very different things in PHP (where it is analogous to copying and pasting source code from another file into the current file) and HTML/JavaScript (where you are referencing another file, which the browser must make a separate HTTP request to download). What do you consider "including"? Are image tags "including" the images? At least we can easily count those references by examining HTTP requests; from the client side, it's impossible to tell what `include()`s went into the source code behind the rendered output. Even naive source code searching couldn't tell you thanks to autoloading. As is, your question is not well enough defined to provide a clear answer.

Comment: I think the OP means references to JavaScript, CSS, image, etc files.

Answer (score 0):

Controversal answer:

- You don't need that.
- If you need that then it's something wrong with the way your designed your application.

***Note:** I've learned (trial and error) that 90% of things I don't know how to do and that seem to be impossible in ZF are a result of wrong application design.*